# How to install program to all user accounts in Windows?

Tags: windows, installation

I have several accounts on my home PC running Windows 8.1. I want to install a program for all user accounts, not just the one I used to perform the installation. How do I go about doing this?

I installed a program from an admin account, but it doesn't show up in the other local accounts.

I was not able to find any documentation on how to do this.

Comment: This functionality depends on how the installer is written. Some installers will give you a choice to install for "this user only" or "all users", others don't have this option. If you don't have this option then try logging in as the other user and installing again.

Answer (score 12):

I assume you're referring to non-metro applications. This answer applies to Windows Vista and later, including Windows 10.

Some program installers only create the application's shortcuts in the account that was used to install the program.  Typically all one needs to do to make the program accessible to all users on the computer is copy these shortcuts to a location that all users can access, such as the Public Desktop or Start Menu. To do so:

1. Find the application's shortcut icon(s) in the installing user's account. Common places where icons are created:

   - User's Start Menu:
     `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`<sup>**1**</sup>
   - User's Desktop:
     `C:\Users\<username>\Desktop`<sup>**2**</sup>
2. Copy the shortcut(s) to one or both of the following locations:

   - All Users' Desktop:
     `C:\Users\Public\Public Desktop`
   - All Users' Start Menu:
     `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`<sup>**3**</sup>

---

<sup>**1**</sup>Also accessible via `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`
<sup>**2**</sup>Also accessible via `%USERPROFILE%\Desktop`
<sup>**3**</sup>Also accessible via `%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`

Comment: `AppData` dir is hidden directory btw. You might need to enable `Show hidden files` in your directory view.