# How Do I Install Teams For Work or School For All Users?

Tags: windows-11, microsoft-teams

I need to use the "Teams for work or school" version of Teams and not the Teams chat version for personal accounts installed with Windows 11.

I downloaded and installed it but it has been installed in the local AppData instead of Program Files.

This computer is used by everyone in the family - each of which need to use the "Teams for work or school" version of Teams.

How do I install it for All Users instead of installing it for every user that needs it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install program to all user accounts in Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/855360/how-to-install-program-to-all-user-accounts-in-windows)

Comment: First, if you need that particular version you should be speaking with the people who require this, the work or school account administrators first. They will have access to enterprise installers that may be more difficult to find online through general searching. Second, it is not wrong to have personal one-user installs for each person who needs the software.

Comment: Enterprise installers generally aren't used for home devices children use for online learning. The question of right or wrong never came up.